# MySQL Distinct (Unique) values over time

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, distinct

I have a question about constructing a MySQL query.  I have a table with one column containing values, and another column containing timestamps.  What I'd like to do is get the number of distinct (unique) values for a field from a specific epoch up until various points in time so that I can plot the number of unique values over time.  For example, I'd like the query result to look like the following:
`Date`, COUNT( DISTINCT `col1`)
2011-02-01, 10
2011-02-02, 16
2011-02-03, 24
etc.

Note that these values are the number of distinct values starting the same point in time.  Currently to accomplish this, I'm using a loop in PHP to iterate a single query for each date and it takes forever since I have a large DB.  To give a better picture, the inefficient code I'd like to replace looks like the following:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dates),$i++){      
    $qry = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT `col1`) FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '".$EPOCH."' AND '".$dates[$i]."';";    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is old, but for posterity, this answer should work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995473/cumulative-monthly-totals-and-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

If understood your question, you can use a GROUP statement:

```
SELECT StampCol, COUNT(DISTINCT DataCol) FROM MyTable GROUP BY StampCol
```

Comment: You need to accumnulate the counts in PHP with that solution.

Comment: Thanks, But this query will give the count for each day (I also need distinct values).  I'm looking for a query where the COUNT includes all `DataCol` values _up until_ the date of the `StampCol`.  This way I can track the growth of unique `DataCol` over time rather than unique `DataCol` per given `StampCol`.

Comment: yes, but with grouping, a unique value for one date group would be counted as unique within the scope of that date-group only, and the count would be off

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date_column, COUNT(visitors) AS visitors FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%Y-%m-%d") ORDER BY date_column desc"
```

Comment: see comment for "If understood your question, you can use a GROUP statement: ...."